# What's the difference between \tikzset and \ctikzset?

Tags: tikz-styles, circuitikz

The fine Circuitikz Manual shows extensive examples of \ctikzset to specify styles for lots of things (my PDF search shows 87 pages with \ctikzset on it).

But, page 22 confuses me.  There, \ctikzset is used to choose ieee style logic ports and a scale factor.

Two paragraphs later, \tikzset (no c) is used to style the flipflops for the example.

I had been sort of operating on the loose principle that, when in Circuitikz, use \ctikzset and when not in Circuitikz, only use \tikzset.  But, it looks like something else is at play here, for the \tikzset still is working.  What am I missing?

Would you please explain what the differences between \ctikzset and \tikzset are?  And, when should I use one or the other?

Comment: I do not think there is a description in the manual, but I will assume that `ctikzset` is equivalent to `pgfplotsset` just for circuiTikZ instead of PGFPlots. `pgfplotsset` is described in the manual starting on page 76. Basically it automatically checks if a key options has both `/tikz/` *and* `/pgfplots/` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is quite easy to explain, and the usage is, well, less. There is a bit of "mess" with historic settings and so on...

Basically, `\ctikzset{key=value}` is the same as `\tikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/key=value}`. It accesses the private namespace of `circuitikz`. In principle, all keys from `circuitikz` should be in that namespace; but that creates a small usability problem sometimes.

Look at this code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,2) to[pR] ++(2,0) node[potentiometershape, right](){};
    \draw (0,1) to[pR, wiper pos=0.9] ++(2,0) node[potentiometershape, right](){};
    % this fails... with an error
    \draw (0,0) to[pR, wiper pos=0.9] ++(2,0) node[potentiometershape, right, wiper pos=0.9](){};
    % and this works
    \draw (0,-1) to[pR, wiper pos=0.9] ++(2,0) node[potentiometershape, right, circuitikz/wiper pos=0.9](){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The fact that `wiper pos` is defined only in the `circuitikz` namespace forces us to use the full prefix when using it in a node specification. For most things, this is not a problem as in this case for example, the `wiper pos` is normally used in a `to` component, where it is possible to add the path to search automatically the private namespace.

But that would be awkward for some things. For example, a lot of components are basically a base one with a set of parameters fiddling, and it's handy to call the component as `node[name]` directly or put the options directly in the `[]` part of the environment: in that case, often the keys "spills" into the global scope, which is the `\tikzset` one. So for example `ieee ports` is also defined as

`\tikzset{ieee ports/.style = {/tikz/circuitikz/logic ports = ieee}}`

so you can use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[ieee ports]
...
\end{tikzpicure}
```

I know, it's a bit of a mess, but it is basically an historic reason... I am trying to pollute the global space the minimum I can, but sometimes it's quite impossible.